# is there a way to have a menulist that opens using an input instead of the menu button in chakra UI?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

i am trying to put together a search bar using chakra ui but it seems like the typical menu example is one where it is a button and you click it and it shows the results.

however, what i want is an input field that shows results once the user starts typing in it/clicks on it.

this is my code for my input field:

```
<InputGroup>
        <Input
          fontFamily="Inter"
          fontSize="20px"
          bgColor="#FFF7F4"
          borderRadius="100px"
          size="md"
          w="full"
          placeholder="Search programs from institutions across Ontario"
          _placeholder={{ color: "black", opacity: "100%" }}
        />
        <InputRightAddon
          p="0"
          bgColor="#FFF7F4"
          children={<AiOutlineSearch bgColor="black" />}
          as={Button}
        ></InputRightAddon>
</InputGroup>
```

this is the code for the menu list. if only there was a way to open the menu using the input and without the menu button.

```
<Menu>
        <MenuButton as={Button}>Actions</MenuButton>
        <MenuList>
          {data.map((value, key) => {
            return (
              // <a href={value.link}>
              //   <p>{value.title}</p>
              // </a>
              <MenuItem>{value.title}</MenuItem>
            );
          })}
        </MenuList>
</Menu>
```

i'm new to chakra ui but i've seen people mess around with the component under the hood and also use `as` property but the latter i didn't have success with.
any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

you can use onChange with useEffect function of ES6/7 javascript module in react js so that, when an user just type a word he may get the result.
Thanks hope you like my answer, if you face any issue just lemme know. I'll try my best to solve your query.